# $\sigma$-field generated from $C = \{\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$ when $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $C = \{\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$ and $C = \{\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$.

Find the $\sigma$-field generated by $C$.

*Attempted Solution*:

$\sigma(C) = \{\Omega, \phi, \{1,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{2,4,5,6\}, \{1,3,5,6\}\}$

*Question*:

Is the above the smallest $\sigma$-field containing $C$ and/or is it correct?

The reason I stopped with the above is that the complements of the last two sets were already given by the original

Thanks!

Comment: The number of elements of a finite $\sigma$-algebra is always a power of $2$.  You are missing $\{5,6\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ in your $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a $\sigma$-field since $\{1,3\}\cup\{2,4\}=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ does not belong to this set. The right answer should be 
$$
\sigma(C) = \{\Omega, \varnothing, \{1,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{2,4,5,6\}, \{1,3,5,6\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}\}
$$
The last set is the complement to $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I was too focused on including the complements and forgot about the unions!

Comment: And the hint from comment above is very useful too: it cannot be $\sigma$-field with $6$ sets total. If you found $6$, you should find two more sets to bring the total to the nearest power of two.